# Exporting XLS into DataTable - Rows Unsorted

Tags: c#, datatable, oledb, xls

I am exporting an .xls file into datatable. Below are my code:

```
private DataTable ExportXlsToDt(String path)
{
    OleDbConnection MyConnection = null;
    DataSet DtSet = null;
    OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand = null;
    MyConnection = new OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source='" + path + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");

    ArrayList TblName = new ArrayList();

    MyConnection.Open();
    DataTable schemaTable = MyConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
    foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
    {
        TblName.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"]);
    }

    MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + TblName[0].ToString() + "]", MyConnection);
    DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();

    MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
    MyCommand.FillSchema(DtSet, SchemaType.Source);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = DtSet.Tables[0];
    MyConnection.Close();
}
```

However the rows after export is not as sorted as rows before export.
Example:

**Original**

```
row A

row B

row C

row D
```

**After Export**

```
row D

row C

row A

row B
```

Can someone advise me on this?

Thank's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have no 'order by' clause on your select; therefore row order isn't guaranteed.
Add an 'order by' clause to `MyCommand` and you should be good.